# Google Plus Sign In Account Selection Dialog Issue

Tags: android, google-plus, firebase-authentication, google-signin

**BACKGROUND**

I am using Google Plus OAuth in my app along with Firebase. When the user taps the sign in button, and account selection dialog appears and the user selects the particular account of choice and signs in.

**PROBLEM**

Suppose the user has two accounts in that device, A and B. Initially, he selects account A to sign in and then uses the app and then decides to sign out. Now he clicks the sign in button again, but **the account selection dialog doesn't appear** and it automatically signs in using the previously selected account A.

**WHAT I WANT**

I want the user to be presented with the account selection dialog every time and **give them a chance to select a different account** if they want to.

**CODE**

Here is a small code snippet of how I am using the Google Api Client for sign in.

```
  String mClientId = parcel.getProviderExtra().getString(CLIENT_ID_KEY);
        GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions;

        googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(mClientId)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

and sign out,

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can logout the user before mGoogleApiClient.connect(); with app. conditions

Comment: The sign out API doesn't help. The dialog doesn't show when the user logs out. The only way is to clear data, that clears some preference that it stores and then the dialog starts appearing again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this resolved by clearing the default account every time before sign in.

```
@Override
    public void startLogin(Activity activity, String mEmail) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        /**
         * Clearing default account every time so that the account picker dialog can be enforced
         */
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
        }
        activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

This will enforce the dialog to appear every time.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void revokeAccess() {
        googleSignInClient.revokeAccess()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        // ...
                        Log.d(LOGTAG, " /// revokeAccess() /// ");
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the default account everytime the user sign's in, by using the method below.

```
    private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
    }
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Firebase 16+ add       mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess();

```
// Full Code
private void startGoogleSignIn() {
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(Splash.this, gso);
            mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess();
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
```